# Cómo puedo hacer sumas y restas usando un input type=text con un input type=date en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un ejemplo pero solo sumando dos `input type=date`, ahora quiero hacer lo mismo pero con con un input type=date y un input type=text

```
<input type="date" id="dateini" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" >                

 <br>

<input type="date" id="datefin" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" 
value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" >              

  <br>                 
            <!--FUNCION PARA CALCULAR LOS DÍAS--->
            <script>
               function calcular(){
var fechaini = new Date(document.getElementById('dateini').value);
var fechafin = new Date(document.getElementById('datefin').value);
var diasdif= fechafin.getTime()-fechaini.getTime();
var contdias = Math.round(diasdif/(1000*60*60*24));
document.form.resultado.value=contdias;
                }
            </script>   


 <label>Días solicitados: </label>
 <input type="text" size="4px" id="resultado" readonly="readonly"   
   name="resultado" onkeypress="return valida(event)" />   

   <br>

   <input type="button" class="bt" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()"/>
```

Comment: Considero que no esta claro lo que preguntas. Intenta plantear un problema concreto, así puedes recibir una respuesta al mismo.

Comment: Quieres sumar/restar días a una fecha?

Comment: Si, pero no se como :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva:

Link: https://codepen.io/logoys/pen/PRoZxJ

HTML:

```
<p>
  <button onclick="calcular('2018-03-08', 'sumar', '2')">Calcular</button>
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

JS:

var resultado = document.querySelector("#resultado");

```
function calcular(fecha, operacion, dias) {
  var date = fecha.split("-"),
      hoy = new Date(date[0], date[1], date[2]),
      dias = parseInt(dias),
      calculado = new Date(),
      dateResul = operacion == "sumar" ? hoy.getDate() + dias : hoy.getDate() - dias;
  calculado.setDate(dateResul);

  resultado.innerText =
    calculado.getDate() +
    "/" +
    (calculado.getMonth() + 1) +
    "/" +
    calculado.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Buena, gracias ahora ya encontre para sumarlas de manera automatica, ahora solo me falta saber el de restar, mira te comparto el código

Comment: function sumDias(fecha, numDias){
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + numDias);
  return fecha;
}

$('#NumDias').on('keyup', function(){
   var numDias = parseInt($('#NumDias').val());
   if (isNaN(numDias)) { 
    $('#Resultado').text('');
    return; 
   }
   var fechaActual = new Date();
   var fechaCalculada = sumDias(fechaActual, numDias);
   $('#Resultado').text(fechaCalculada.toLocaleDateString());
});

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Nº días: <input type="numeric" id="NumDias" />

<br/><br/>

Resultado: <span id="Resultado"></span>

Comment: Amigo, la respuesta que te publiquè tienes ambias opciones, solo fijate en los paràmetros de la funciòn calcular, solo quita "sumar" y ponle "restar.

Comment: Si es verdad tienes, razón, ahora solo falta averiguar como obtengo el valor de otros input para que los valores no sean estaticos en la función calcular